# Write N/A or " - " on empty cells if one cell of the same row is written

Tags: excel

What I am trying to do is this;

I have a table with 8 columns. 
What I am trying to do is when I write something in one of the first 4 columns in the same row the other 3 should return me with the value "N/A" or " - ", or something like that. (Or even better with an error message saying I can't write on them since one of the other is written).

The same with the other rows in the table.

Here is the table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdpsP.png)

I've tried with IF(OR(ISBLACK( etc. but it wasn't working.

So if i write something on cell B3, the other cells (C3,D3,E3) will have to be empty, the same as if i write something on cell C3, the other cells(B3,D3,E3) should be empty.

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like, and what you have tried so far? There isn't enough to work with here.

Comment: Using VBA, it is possible to to check for a cell value change, then lock/unlock relevant cells on a protected worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using formulas, with each column have a formula that checks the other columns. For example, B3 would have:

`=IF(OR(C3<>"",D3<>"",E3<>""),"Do not use","")`

But the problem with formulas in data entry spaces is they get overwritten when users enter data. If the user changes their mind and deletes the value they entered, you don't get the formula back and warning won't reappear when they enter data elsewhere.

Instead, you can use conditional formatting to change the colour of cells without values after a value gets entered:

1. Select B1:E16 (starting from B1 is important, as relative conditional formatting depends on which cell is active within the selection)
2. Create a new Custom Formatting rule based on a formula: `=AND(COUNTA($B3:$E3)>0,B3="")`
3. Set the format to make the background gray

This doesn't stop users entering data in more than cell. You may want to put in another additional conditional formatting rule to set cells red if there is more than 1 value entered.